# Files are marked as missing, when they're really not

Tags: svn

This is very weird. In my company's subversion repository, there is a set of files in this one directory that are all marked as missing. That means when I do "svn status", they all have the "!" next to them.

They are all in the same directory, which is probably important for why this is happening, even though I don't understand it.

Anyway, the files are there. They are absolutely, 100% present on my local system. They're also tracked in SVN, the only reason they're on my local system is because they were downloaded when I pulled down an update. Yet they are marked as missing.

I'm trying to figure out why this is happening and make the marker go away, because I like having my svn status produce clean results. I've tried reverting the files, re-downloading, etc, nothing seems to work.

Comment: did you check file permissions?

Comment: it's weird though, I got the files in the first place from SVN. These are not files I created on my system, they're in SVN

Comment: And nope, I just checked, they all have the same permissions. There are 27 files in this directory, 12 of them are showing as "missing" (they have the "!"), and all of them have the exact same owner:group and permissions (644, I'm on Mac).